# Design time only view properties

Tags: ios, interface-builder

Is it possible to set certain UIView property (eg. background color) to be used only at design time in interface builder?

Reason is that I have some custom controls, that does not have render themselves in interface builder different than plain UIView so they doesn't stand out from background.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you can do such a thing only with constraints. If you want to set the color for a `UIView` which will distinguish it from its background you have to overwrite it somewhere. For example, in a `UIView` subclass, you can do it in an initializer or in `awakeFromNib` method.

Another option is using `IB_DESIGNABLE` and setting the color in the `initWithFrame` initializer which is used by the Xcode for prerendering of your custom views.